# Slider with tabs under banner image

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for slider similar to:
[image]

I have created use materializecss but when I put this code on our website then this code destroyed all styles in our website.

Can anyone have any solution how to solve or any other solution for this slider?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Materialize Tabs Example</title>
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">      
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel = "stylesheet" 
         href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
      <script type = "text/javascript"
         src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>           
      <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js">
      </script> 
   </head>
   
   <body class = "container"> 
      <div class = "row">

         
         <div id = "inbox" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
         <div id = "unread" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
         <div id = "outbox" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
         <div id = "sent" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
                  <div class = "col s12">
            <ul class = "tabs">
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a href = "#inbox">Inbox</a></li>
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a class = "active" href = "#unread">
                  Unread</a></li>
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a href = "#outbox">
                  Outbox (Disabled)</a></li>
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a href = "#sent">Sent</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tabs has swipebable option. I've enabled it and update materialize to v1.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>The Materialize Tabs Example</title>
      <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">      
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    </head>
    <body class = "container"> 
      <div class = "row">
         <div id = "inbox" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
         <div id = "unread" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
         <div id = "outbox" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
         <div id = "sent" class = "col s12"><img src="https://iv.pl/images/52b0f0c1074fd3b882aeb3f7f5460ee5.png"></div>
                  <div class = "col s12">
            <ul class = "tabs">
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a href = "#inbox">Inbox</a></li>
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a class = "active" href = "#unread">
                  Unread</a></li>
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a href = "#outbox">
                  Outbox (Disabled)</a></li>
               <li class = "tab col s3"><a href = "#sent">Sent</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div> 
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>         
     <script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.tabs').tabs({ swipeable: true });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Zubenki Unfortunately, I don't have the knowledge to make it myself. Can you help us?

Comment: I see that your code have tabs and photo changed when tab button is active. What exactly do you want to do? Slide photos on clicking tab or slide on timer?

Comment: thanks for reply. I need slide  photos on clicing tab (effect sliding left or right)

Comment: Can you help us do this?

Comment: Zubeko, thank you for your help. Working perfect ;)